# INI File configuration handler

Tags: c, configuration

I am currently working on a game, and I get the configuration in an .ini file, and I get information with this library https://github.com/benhoyt/inih I would like to improve the readability / performance of this code, as I do not know much about good practices.

```
include "project.h"

// typedef struct s_server_conf {
//      const char              *ip;
//      unsigned int    port;
// }                            t_server_conf;

// typedef struct       s_db_conf {
//      const char              *host;
//      const char              *user;
//      const char              *passwd;
//      const char              *db;
//      unsigned int    port;
// }                            t_db_conf;

// typedef struct s_conf {
//      t_server_conf   server;
//      t_db_conf               conf;
// }                            t_conf;

static int      parse_server(t_conf *conf, const char *name, const char *value)
{
        # define MATCH(n) (strcmp(name, n) == 0)

        if (MATCH("ip"))
                conf->server->ip = strdup(value);
        else if (MATCH("port"))
                conf->server->port = atoi(value);
        else
                return (0);
        return (1);
}

static int      parse_database(t_conf *conf, const char *name, const char *value)
{
        # define MATCH_NAME(n) (strcmp(name, n) == 0)

        if (MATCH_NAME("host"))
                conf->db->host = (strdup(value));
        else if (MATCH_NAME("user"))
                conf->db->user = (strdup(value));
        else if (MATCH_NAME("passwd"))
                conf->db->passwd = (strdup(value));
        else
                return (0);
        return (1);
}

static int      handler(void *conf, const char *section, const char *name, const char *value)
{
        # define MATCH_SECTION(s) (strcmp(section, s) == 0)

        printf("Le nom du champ est %s, la valeur est %s (La section est %s)\n", name, value, section)
;

        if (MATCH_SECTION("database"))
                return (parse_database((t_conf*)conf, name, value));
        if (MATCH_SECTION("server"))
                return (parse_server((t_conf*)conf, name, value));
        return (0);
}

void            clear_conf(t_conf *conf)
{
        if (conf->db)
                free(conf->db);
        if (conf->server)
                free(conf->server);
        free(conf);
}

static  t_conf          *create_conf(void)
{
        t_conf  *conf;

        if (!(conf = (t_conf*)malloc(sizeof(t_conf))))
                return (NULL);
        memset(conf, '\0', sizeof(t_conf));
        if (!(conf->db = (t_db_conf*)malloc(sizeof(t_db_conf))))
        {
                clear_conf(conf);
                return (NULL);
        }
        conf->db->port = 3306;
        if (!(conf->server = (t_server_conf*)malloc(sizeof(t_server_conf))))
        {
                clear_conf(conf);
                return (NULL);
        }
        return (conf);
}
t_conf          *get_conf(void)
{
        t_conf  *conf;

        if (!(conf = create_conf()))
                return (NULL);
        if (ini_parse("settings.ini", handler, conf) < 0)
        {
                printf("Unable to load configuration\n");
                exit (1);
        }
        return (conf);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Design**

Rather than bury a magic filename, consider passing it in.

```
//t_conf          *get_conf(void) {
//  ... 
//    if (ini_parse("settings.ini", handler, conf) < 0)

t_conf *get_conf(const char *ini_file_name) {
  ... 
  if (ini_parse(ini_file_name, handler, conf) < 0)
```

Maybe add before the `if()`

```
  if (ini_file_name == NULL) {
    ini_file_name = "settings.ini";
  }
```

**Devoid of overall comments**

Consider comments to at least convey the coding goals.

**Allocate to the size of the de-referenced object**

... rather than allocate to the size of the type - easier to code right, review and maintain.  Cast not needed.

```
//if (!(conf = (t_conf*)malloc(sizeof(t_conf))))
//            return (NULL);
conf = malloc(sizeof *conf);
if (conf == NULL) {
  return NULL;
}

// like-wise
// memset(conf, '\0', sizeof(t_conf));
memset(conf, 0, sizeof *conf);
```

**Use auto formatting**

Life is too short for manual formatting. Find and use an auto formatter - customized as needed.

**Comments of typedefs not needed**

As is now, this code has comments that is not required to match what is truly in `"project.h"` and as time goes on, can diverge.  For code posting here, post a portion of `"project.h"` instead.

**Invalid code**

`include "project.h"` should be `#include "project.h"`

**Hiding objects here is bad**

`# define MATCH(n) (strcmp(name, n) == 0)` brings in `name`, but not obvious from the call `if (MATCH("ip"))`.

Alternative:

```
static bool streq(const char *a, const char *b) {
  return strcmp(a,b) == 0;
}
...
if (streq(name, "ip"))
```

**Naked magic number**

Buried in code is

```
conf->db->port = 3306;
```

Better to have

```
// near top of code
#define PORT_DEFAULT 3306

// later on
conf->db->port = PORT_DEFAULT;
```

**Unneeded `if`**

Just call `free()`.  `free(NULL)` is OK.

```
//if (conf->db)
//            free(conf->db);
free(conf->db);
```

Like `free()`, I'd expect `clear_conf(NULL)` to not error

```
void clear_conf(t_conf *conf) {
  if (conf) { // add
```

**() not needed in `return` and others**

Many places

```
// return (conf);
return conf;

// conf->db->host = (strdup(value));
conf->db->host = strdup(value);
```

**Non-standard C**

Note: `strdup()` is not standard, yet ubiquitous.

**Missing `#include <>`**

Do not rely on "project.h" to provide them unless that is clearly a project rule.

**`NULL` as `name`**

Given the potential generic use of `handler`, I'd guard against `NULL`.

```
// printf("Le nom du champ est %s, la valeur est %s (La section est %s)\n", name, value, section);
if (name === NULL || value == NULL || section == NULL) {
  tbd();
} else {
  printf("Le nom du champ est %s, la valeur est %s (La section est %s)\n", name, value, section);
}
```

Further I'd bracket such strings to help detect leading/trailing white spaces in them

```
  printf("Le nom du champ est \"%s\", la valeur est \"%s\" (La section est \"%s\")\n",
      name, value, section);
```

**Lack of error checking**

```
// what if `value` is "", "abc", "123xyz", "12345678901234567890", ...?
conf->server->port = atoi(value);

// what if allocation returns NULL? 
conf->server->ip = strdup(value);
```

**Respect presentation width**

```
        printf("Le nom du champ est %s, la valeur est %s (La section est %s)\n", name, value, section)
;
```

vs.

```
        printf("Le nom du champ est %s, la valeur est %s (La section est %s)\n",
            name, value, section);
```

Another reason for an auto formatter.

**Curious dual language**

I'd expect one.

```
printf("Le nom du champ est %s, la valeur est %s (La section est %s)\n", ...
printf("Unable to load configuration\n");
```

**Conversion changes sign-ness**

```
unsigned port;
...
conf->server->port = atoi(value);
```

Perhaps a helper function

```
// return error status
bool to_unsigned(unsigned *u, const char *s) {
  if (s == NULL) {
    return true;
  }
  char *endptr;
  errno = 0;
  unsigned long = strtoul(s, &endptr, 10); 
  if (errno || s == endptr || *endptr || value > UINT_MAX) {
    return true;
  }

  if (u) {
    *u = (unsigned) value;
  }
  return false;
}

if (to_unsigned(&conf->server->port, value)) {
  hanlde_oops();
}
```